# Sort Pandas DataFrame with list column

Tags: pandas, list, sorting, pivot

I have a dataframe I created from a pivot table like this:

| mykey | values1 | values2 | values3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,2,0] | [2,3,5] | [2,3,4] |
| 3 | [2,1] | [3,1] | [2,1] |

I want to sort the lists in the dataframe in ascending order by values1 and have that ordering reflected in the ordering of values2 and values3 like this:

| mykey | values1 | values2 | values3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [0,1,2] | [5,2,3] | [4,2,3] |
| 3 | [1,2] | [1,3] | [1,2] |

Right now, I sorted the input values to the arrays before creating the pivot table and that seems to work, but I thought there would likely be a way to sort the pivot table after it is created as above.

Comment: That's pretty tricky. You could use `numpy.argsort()` to get the indicies which would sort values1, then apply those indicies to values2 and values3.

Comment: What is the logic for sorting? It seems like the logic is the opposite order for each cell?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I edited the OP above. I want to sort by values1 in ascending order.

Comment: What about Values 2 and 3? It is not clear how those are geing sorted. EDIT: I think now I get it. Yo uare sorting by the INDEX/position of each item according to values1.

Comment: I want those to be sorted in the same using the sorted indices from values1. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @user3329712 how important is performance? I will post a quick and dirty `pandas` solution, but I think there will be a much more efficient `numpy` solution, but I have to run soon.

Comment: Yes! sorted by the index of sorted items from values1

Comment: Performance is pretty important, and yeah I was thinking numpy might be the way to go as well in that case.

Comment: @user3329712 kindly test the performance on my solution. I would be curious to know how good the performance is on x rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode all of the columns simultaneously with `df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` into a longer dataframe in preparation for sorting. Then, `.groupby` back into a list, now in the desired order:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'mykey' : [1, 3],
'values1' : [[1,2,0], [2,1]],
'values2' : [[2,3,5], [3,1]],
'values3' : [[2,3,4], [2,1]]})
df = (df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
      .reset_index()
      .sort_values(['mykey', 'values1'])
      .drop('index', axis=1)
      .groupby('mykey') # Passing 'sort=False' could have a minor performance boost even though already sorted.
      .agg(list)
      .reset_index())
df
Out[1]: 
   mykey    values1    values2    values3
0      1  [0, 1, 2]  [5, 2, 3]  [4, 2, 3]
1      3     [1, 2]     [1, 3]     [1, 2]
```

Comment: So, I did not just want to reverse the order of the lists, and updated the OP above. But thank you for posting this!